# Phonegap barcode plugin only one format

Tags: windows, cordova, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to set up two scan zones in my cordova application under windows 10 (UWP x64).

One field detects only CODE_39 and the other QR_CODE.

According to the documentation I used this code:

```
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
  function (result) {
      alert("We got a barcode\n" +
            "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
            "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
            "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
  },
  function (error) {
      alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
  },
  {
      formats : "QR_CODE"
  });
```

But the "format" option doesn't seem to work because I can scan CODE_39, QR_CODE, PDF_417... in each area.

Is the option not available on Windows 10? Am I misusing the option?

CORDOVA : 6.3.1

CORDOVA WINDOWS : 4.3.3

PLUGIN SCAN : 7.1.2

Comment: Solved!
First of all, I can't use 7.1.2 because this version doesn't work with UWP.
So I used version 6.0.1 to scan with my applications but in this version the format option did not work.
So I searched in the public github of the project and noticed that the format option is only available under windows from this commit (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/commit/1f016d9564a494cf0ecc86c41be89fabdfa9fa3f) and therefore version 7.0.0 which works under windows.
The solution is to use version 7.0.0 of the plugin.